# How to disable country dropdown in Stripe checkout?

Tags: api, stripe-payments

I am selling / shipping to continental US only and would like to disable (make it read only or completely remove it if not possible to make it read only) the country drop-down:

[image]

I am using this javascript format:

```
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-name="Secure Payment Via Stripe"
data-description="100% Arabica Roasted Coffee Beans - 1 lb"
data-allow-remember-me="false"
data-locale="en"
data-billingAddress="true"
data-shippingAddress="true">
</script>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can prefill these field before creating the checkout session.